# scroll extend jQuery like facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, scroll, extend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {
            jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
                {   
                    'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                    'url': 'components/com_a_main_search/more_content.php?limit='+???????, 
                    'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content'
                }
            );

        }
    );
   </script>
```

How can pass incremental value instead of "???????"

Thanks for help

Comment: Use a variable and do some operations on it and then use it in the place of ???????.

Answer (score 0):

store it in a variable and pass it.

for eg. )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(
          $inc = 1;
        function() {
            jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
                {   
                    'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                    'url': 'components/com_a_main_search/more_content.php?limit='+$inc, 
                    'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content'
                }
            );

        }
    );
   </script>
```

I 'm not very sure if this is what you are looking for as I couldn't have any better understanding from the question.